# deleting a string from a text file and then saving the new file in place of the original

Tags: batch-file

I am working with a software that will output a text file containing various information regarding the measurement runs. I want to edit this file so that a certain set of strings can be deleted and then save this new file. Below is sample of the text file.

---

```
featureListName All Characteristics
meMode  cf
naviMode    automatic
pdfExport   false
presProtocol    false
printer false
printPlots  false
protNumbers 1
protocolDefinition  nil
protocolHead    true
psExport    false
ptxExport   false
runMode slowToFirst
selection   nil
speed   300
changedate  July 5, 2017   10:00:35 am
changeoper  Master
changeswi   6.2.1602
changeTimestamp 3676701635
changeTimestampOld  3676701635
creationdate    July 5, 2017   9:57:53 am
creationdme Prismo
creationswi 6.2.1602
date    2017-7-5
dateandtime July 5, 2017 5:05:53 pm
datedayofmonth  5
datemonthindex  7
datesecondclock 3676745153
datestring  July 5, 2017
dateyear    2017
dmeid   Prismo
dmesn   000000
drawingno    
mccplanversion  
nameOfFile  c:\Users\Public\Documents\Zeiss\CALYPSO\workarea\inspections\test
operid  Master
order    
partnbinc   3
partnbpre   3
planid  test
produceoper Master
runswv  6.2.1602
time    5:05:53 pm
u_field1    
u_field2    
u_field3    
u_field4    Contura1
```

---

My goal in editing this file is to remove the string "Contura1" and then save the file in the same directory with the same name. Any insight as to how I can accomplish this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove the line containing the string or just the string? And if the latter what about tabs/spaces in front of the string? Have a look at the `findstr /?` command. Please note that [SO] isn't a script writing service. And there are tons of similar batches to be found via the search box above.

Comment: You are going to have to do some type of script, maybe powershell. Please tag the question with the language that you are going to try to use.

Comment: @Chuck - He did.

Comment: I would like to remove the entire line. Thank you for the input, I am brand spankin' new to this.